# Display a Blob image from MySQL database using Angular 5

Tags: java, typescript, angular5

I have a class with a Blob field called logo, when i want to display this field i am not sure how to do it in Angular, and if Blob is the best type to store images knowing that the app is a small app with few users.

**Company.java**

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;  
    @Column(name = "activity", nullable = false)
    private String activity;
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "logo", nullable = true)
    private Blob logo;
}
```

**model.company.ts**

```
export class Company{
  public id:any;
  public name:string;
  public activity:string;
  public address:string;
  public city:string;
  public logo:Blob;
}
```

when i do it this way it doesn't show anything even other fields which are strings.

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of pageCompanies?.content">
    <td class="py-1"><img src="{{c.logo}}" class="rounded-circle" width="45" height="45"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I recommend you, change logo field to String, upload files to the server, and save the file path

Answer (score 1):

Have you saved your logo as base64??

If not try the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of pageCompanies?.content">
   <td class="py-1"><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{c.logo}}" class="rounded-circle" width="45" height="45"></td>
</tr>
```